# When declaring a subPropertyOf, can I restrict rdfs:domain just like I restrict rdfs:range?

Tags: declaration, owl, ontology, protege

I'm learning to use Protégé and OWL.
I'm wondering if, when creating a sub-property, I can declare a domain instead of just using the inherited one.

For example:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="isBrother">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="#isSibling" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Human">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Male">
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

Given that #isSibling has #Human as a domain.

I don't see why not but I couldn't find a clear answer yet.

Comment: Adding a domain to a subproperty doesn't overwrite the domain of the superproperty. It's just an additional axiom because reasoning is monotonic. As a result, every subject having a isBrother fact will belong to both Human and Male class. So in your case it doesn't matter, in other cases it could be unintended